# Laravel - Check storage folder permissions through custom php script

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I don't know how laravel handles it, but can anybody give me a quick overview of how does laravel check folder permissions (storage and bootstrap)?

I have tried using `is_writable("storage")` but it doesn't seem to work atleast on a laravel installation on WAMP server. It gives true every time I try to run it.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: who says it is checking permissions?

Comment: When the storage folder has read only permissions in windows, it gives an error trying to access a log file. "Permission denied".

Comment: Laravel isn't checking anything, this is what happens when you try to write to something you don't have permission to, that is the OS responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run according to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master#configuration) (Directory Permissions
 section).

So it's obvious that `is_writable("storage")` will always return true on your running Laravel app.

**Note**: You can use following commands to configure directory permissions after installing Laravel:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: I accept that as an answer as I have found a way to accomplish what I wanted clearly through this explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have `bootstrap/cache` in my directory.
where should I put `is_writable("storage")`